# How to read Map values from foreach in scala

Tags: json, scala

```
// Reads Json file                           
val input_file = ("\\path\\to\\MyNew.json");

val json_content = scala.io.Source.fromFile(input_file).mkString
// parsing the json file
val details = JSON.parseFull(json_content)
// checking the matched result
details match {
    case mayBeList: Some[Map[String, Any]] =>
    val z = mayBeList.get.tails.toSet.flatten 
    z.foreach(println)
    case None => println("Parsing failed")
    case other => println("Unknown data structure: " + other)
}
```

getting following Output:

```
Map(Name -> Harish, Company -> In Equity, Sal -> 50000)
Map(Name -> Veer, Company -> InOut, Sal -> 20000)
Map(Name -> Zara, Company -> InWhich, Sal -> 90000)
Map(Name -> Singh, Company -> InWay, Sal -> 30000)
Map(Name -> Chandra, Company -> InSome, Sal -> 60000)
```

**Expected Output**

```
Harish, In Quality, 50000- (only values of Map)
```

Comment: Can you provide the content of the file you're using as input?

Comment: `Map` has `.values` method

Comment: [{

  "Name": "Harish",
  "Company": "In Equity",
  "Sal": "50000"
},
  {

    "Name": "Chandra",
    "Company": "InSome",
    "Sal": "60000"
  },
  {

    "Name": "Singh",
    "Company": "InWay",
    "Sal": "30000"
  },
  {

    "Name": "Veer",
    "Company": "InOut",
    "Sal": "20000"
  },
  {

    "Name": "Zara",
    "Company": "InWhich",
    "Sal": "90000"
  }]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to iterate though the elements of your `list` i.e. `z` and extract values from each `map` like this,

```
List(Map("Name" -> "Harish", "Company" -> "In Equity", "Sal" -> 50000),
  Map("Name" -> "Veer", "Company" -> "InOut", "Sal" -> 20000),
  Map("Name" -> "Zara", "Company" -> "InWhich", "Sal" -> 90000),
  Map("Name" -> "Singh", "Company" -> "InWay", "Sal" -> 30000),
  Map("Name" -> "Chandra", "Company" -> "InSome", "Sal" -> 60000)
)
.map(_.values.toList).foreach(println)
//List[List[Any]] = List(List(Harish, In Equity, 50000), List(Veer, InOut, 20000), List(Zara, InWhich, 90000), List(Singh, InWay, 30000), List(Chandra, InSome, 60000))
```

Hope this helps you.

**Update**

In response to your comment, use this code

```
import scala.util.parsing.json._

val input_file = ("C:\\Users\\VishalK\\IdeaProjects\\ScalaCassan\\src\\main\\scala\\MyNew.json");

val json_content = scala.io.Source.fromFile(input_file)
// parsing the json file

val details: Option[Any] = JSON.parseFull(json_content.mkString)

details match {
  case mayBeList: Some[Any] =>
    mayBeList.getOrElse(Seq.empty[Map[String, Any]]).asInstanceOf[List[Map[String, Any]]].map(_.values.toList).toSet
  case None => println("Parsing failed")
}
```

in your match block :

- In first case I don't get why you are using `.tails.toSet.flatten` on `Any` data type.
- You can remove the third case as `Some` and `None` are the only possible outcomes of `Option` data-type.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: details match {
    case mayBeList: Some[Map[String, Any]] =>
      val z = mayBeList.get.tails.toList.flatten

     z.map(_.values).foreach(x => println(x.toList.mkString(", ")))
  
    case None => println("Parsing failed")
    case other => println("Unknown data structure: " + other)
  }
throwing the following error..:   Error:(26, 14) value values is not a member of (String, Any)
     z.map(_.values).foreach(x => println(x.toList.mkString(", ")))

Comment: the above mentioned solution is not type safe. It will work only for data in the format of `[{"Name" : "Harish","Company" : "In Equity","Sal" : "50000"}, {"Name" : "Veer","Company" : "InOut","Sal" : "20000"}]`. Can you also show what is the JSON structure you are providing?

Comment: Also can you tell me why are you using `mayBeList.get.tails.toSet.flatten ` on `Any` data type?

Comment: json:::: [{ "Name": "Harish", "Company": "In Equity", "Sal": "50000" }, { "Name": "Chandra", "Company": "InSome", "Sal": "60000" }, { "Name": "Singh", "Company": "InWay", "Sal": "30000" }, { "Name": "Veer", "Company": "InOut", "Sal": "20000" }, { "Name": "Zara", "Company": "InWhich", "Sal": "90000" }]   i am using "toSet.flatten" because it gives me uniqueu results where as if i use "toList" then it is giving me duplicate records.

Comment: Modified code should work for the given JSON structure. To get unique values all you need to do is use `SET` at right place like : `mayBeList.getOrElse(Seq.empty[Map[String, Any]]).asInstanceOf[List[Map[String, Any]]].map(_.values.toList)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `.values` for the values and `.keys` for the keys.

```
val m: Map[String, Int] = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)

m.values // res0: Iterable[Int] = MapLike(1, 2)
m.keys // res1: Iterable[String] = Set(a, b)
```

Comment: Obviously you can convert these to a List or Seq or whatever with the relevant `.to...` method (eg `.toList`, `toSeq`, etc).

Comment: Hi James thanks for your reply, but its throwing an error for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> val l = List(Map("Name" -> "Harish", "Company" -> "In Equity", "Sal" -> 50000),
     |   Map("Name" -> "Veer", "Company" -> "InOut", "Sal" -> 20000),
     |   Map("Name" -> "Zara", "Company" -> "InWhich", "Sal" -> 90000),
     |   Map("Name" -> "Singh", "Company" -> "InWay", "Sal" -> 30000),
     |   Map("Name" -> "Chandra", "Company" -> "InSome", "Sal" -> 60000)
     | )
l: List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any]] = List(Map(Name -> Harish, Company -> In Equity, Sal -> 50000), Map(Name -> Veer, Company -> InOut, Sal -> 20000), Map(Name -> Zara, Company -> InWhich, Sal -> 90000), Map(Name -> Singh, Company -> InWay, Sal -> 30000), Map(Name -> Chandra, Company -> InSome, Sal -> 60000))

scala> l.map(_.values).foreach(x => println(x.toList.mkString(", ")))
Harish, In Equity, 50000
Veer, InOut, 20000
Zara, InWhich, 90000
Singh, InWay, 30000
Chandra, InSome, 60000
```

Comment: Hi airudah, thanks for your reply, but here you are hardcoding key and value pair in List(Map)) but the program i have written is reading json file dynamically, for which i need individual record values.